# Ldap find one query returns null result when deployed to IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, ldap, windows-authentication, ldap-query, iis-10

I have written a LDAP query to find user groups using user name. It works fine when I run it in VS2012 on the iis express. It always returns a null result when deployed to IIS 10.

```
string _path = Convert.ToString(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LDAPROOTURL"]);
string strName = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.ToString().Split('\\')[1].Replace(".", " ");
string ldapname = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(strName);

DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(_path);
search.Filter = "(cn=" + ldapname + ")";
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
StringBuilder groupNames = new StringBuilder();

try
{
    SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
    if (result != null)
    {
        int propertyCount = result.Properties["memberOf"].Count;

        String dn;
        int equalsIndex, commaIndex;

        for (int propertyCounter = 0; propertyCounter < propertyCount; propertyCounter++)
        {
            dn = (String)result.Properties["memberOf"][propertyCounter];

            equalsIndex = dn.IndexOf("=", 1);
            commaIndex = dn.IndexOf(",", 1);
            if (-1 == equalsIndex)
            {
                return null;
            }

            groupNames.Append(dn.Substring((equalsIndex + 1), (commaIndex - equalsIndex) - 1));
            groupNames.Append("|");

        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Error obtaining group names. " + ex.Message);
}
return Convert.ToString(groupNames);
```

Enabled only in windows authentication.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, why query is not working after deploying in IIS 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name` with `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` and see if you get different results.

If `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` is empty, then your Windows Authentication isn't working properly.